# Convert simple select result into 2D transposed table

Tags: mysql

I have a table of tennis match results for a league. There are only three columns: Player1, Player2 and MatchResult.

Players are listed in col A or col B depending on weather the player is home or away player. If listed in col A, than it is a home player, if listed in col B, than it is an away player. So for example player with name G will sometimes appear in col A and sometimes in col B.

Match result can have two or three parts, separated by comma. First part is for set 1, second part for set2 and optional third part is for set 3. Each result for each set first lists home player, than semicolon and than away  player.

If we took the first example from the attached image, explanation would be the following: Player1 named F has lost the match against Player2 named B in the following way:
- Player B has won first set 6:2
- Player F has won second set 6:3
- Player B has won third set 13:11

[image]

I would like to transpose the table into a 2D format, like on the image attached. That is, each player name would be first listed on X an Y table axis and than each result would have to fit into the correct table cell twice. Once as home/away player standing point of view, and than also a away/home player standing point of view (red text color).

[image]

How would the MySQL select query have to look like to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider constructing a large pivot table, something like this:

```
SELECT
    Player1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Player2 = 'A' THEN MatchResult END) AS A,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Player2 = 'B' THEN MatchResult END) AS B,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Player2 = 'C' THEN MatchResult END) AS C,
    ...,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Player2 = 'Z' THEN MatchResult END) AS Z
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Player1
ORDER BY Player1;
```